# webpack imports everything instead of not importing from the dir when alias

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpacker

i have an alias in webpack such as:

```
'test': path.join(__dirname, '..', 'static');
```

I have an entry file `main.js` in which i have this:

```
require('test/' + bux);
```

I also have a file-loader which takes care of images.

Even though bux is undefined in the `main.js`, what really happens is webpack bundles everything that is in `static` folder(all the files, even in the subdirectories of `static` folder. I am curious why? If I remove bux and have `require('test/');` it results in an error

> can't resolve /test.

where is the information about this in docs or something?

Answer (score 0):

First, you use the expression in require, like `require('test/' + bux)`, webpack can't ensure the target module before the expression execution. so webpack bundle all the files under the static folder. and when the expression executes, webpack can require the right module because of all the possible modules all bundled.

you can check the docs [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext)

Second, you should **remove the slash after the `test`**. otherwise, webpack can't find the module.

Take the case of `require('test/')` for example

The step of webpack look for the module would like

1. detect the `test` is alias and replace the actual path for the alias path, and the statement would like this

```
const autual = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'static'); 

require('autual/static/')
```

2. The path is absolute and webpack find no module's path match this. so webpack throw errors.

you can check the [enhanced-resolve](https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve) for more details, which implement the resolve logic for webpack to look for module and loader.